# Fatal error condition occurred in c:209: allocator != ((void *)0) - aws-sdk-cpp

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm having an issue after updating: Upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket using an AWS SDK:(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_PutObject_section.html)

```
int main(int, char **)
{
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    classB::initAwsApi(options);
    
        while (true)
    {

        
        //...
        
        if (threadApi.joinable())
        threadApi.join();
        
        threadApi = std::thread(request, &connection, &headers);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        // if I close the stream, the error doesn't appear. But I would like to close the stream
        stream_.release();
    }
    
    if (threadApi.joinable())
            threadApi.join();

    // when closing the SDK, the error appears
    classB::shutdownAwsApi(options);
}
```

output:
Fatal error condition occurred in /home/x/x/deps/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/source/allocator.c:209: allocator != ((void *)0)
Exiting Application
No call stack information available
Aborted(core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error was in the new version of aws. I lowered the version and compiled it again and it worked

Comment: Do you know which version this error was introduced in?

Comment: @RaphaelSampaio please see https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/8320

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this issue but I got the same error in a slightly different context. In my case it appeared in `__libc_start_main` (this is the function that calls `main`.)

My problem was caused by a global variable that was cleaned up in `__libc_start_main` which occurred after the `Aws::ShutdownAPI` call:

```cpp
inline Aws::S3::S3Client get_s3_client() {
    // HERE! This is a global variable that got destoryed after 'Aws::ShutdownAPI'.
    static std::optional<Aws::S3::S3Client> s3_client;

    if (s3_client.has_value()) {
        return s3_client.value();
    }

    QSettings settings;

    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
    credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId(settings.value("AWS/AccessKeyId").value<QString>().toStdString());
    credentials.SetAWSSecretKey(settings.value("AWS/SecretKey").value<QString>().toStdString());

    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
    clientConfiguration.region = settings.value("AWS/Region").value<QString>().toStdString();

    s3_client.emplace(credentials, clientConfiguration);
    return s3_client.value();
}
```

The problem only became visible after updating the AWS library. I suspect that `Aws::S3::S3Client` did not contain anything that was allocated before and a recent release changed that.